# How to force height of listView to be size so that every row is visible?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have nested listView. How to force height of listView to be size so that every row is visible ?
ListView is nested inside ScrollView so scroll doesn't work for ListView so I need to make that all items are visible inside ListView which is nested ion ScrollView ( there is above and bellow more things).

Comment: You shouldn't be using a `ListView` in that case. A normal vertical `LinearLayout` and repeated calls to `ListAdapter#getView` - that you then add to the `LinearLayout` (just remember to add click listeners).

Comment: Using ListView in ScrollView is not efficient. Reconsider your UI design.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)

Comment: Did you achieved this?

Answer (score 4):

To calculate hieght of listView

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
            MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Pass listview object to this methode.

```
 setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listView)
```

Comment: I have changedv totalHeight += (listItem.MeasuredHeight+45) and  it is ok now, but it is not good solution i know

Comment: Versions I have seen use 'listItem.measure(0, 0);' but also return a significantly larger height when used on a phone with modified DPI values.

Comment: Even if an old answer i want to state that this doesn't work. It could returned very big results such as 1050

Comment: After 10 years of writing this answer, I confirm here that you should not use listview or recyclerview for any of such requirement.

If number of items are decided on runtime, then you should argue on why all need to be shown all at once on one screen without scrolling ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code.listview contains this attribute

```
android:minheight="20dp";
```