# Android ListView item getMeasuredHeight() returns a smaller value than the real one

Tags: android, listview

I've been wrestling with this issue on Android all morning. I have a ListView for which I need to calculate the height.

I am using this code:

```
int totalHeight = 0;
for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
    View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
    listItem.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

which I found here, however - the return value for a certain layout of the list item is smaller than the real one (for others it's accurate), which eventually using it to reset the height of the list cuts away the content of it. I've looked at a lot of threads about this - one offered the solution of making the height of all the objects in the layout "wrap_content", which didn't work for me for example.

I can't find anything that works anywhere. Can anyone help?

Sincerely, 
-Lior

Comment: i want do job like you want but problem is that the height and the width is set when you page is up, and you can worked with height.you must set static height to each row

Comment: I don't understand. This work great with a different layout (I add stuff to the list and then redefine the height).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much search I have found this thread:

[How to force height of listView to be size so that every row is visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484038/how-to-force-height-of-listview-to-be-size-so-that-every-row-is-visible)

that gave me the solution... funny it took me so long to find it as it is a much more accurate than dozens of pages I've hit before it regarding this issue.

Hope this will help to spread the word :)

Lior